# Porque esta pergunta deve ser fechada?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

[Nome de pessoas devem ser armazenados em duas ou apenas uma coluna?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48666/101)

Há votos de não claro. Quem votou nisto pode clarificar aqui como não está claro. Como ser mais claro do que perguntar as vantagens e desvantagens de usar um modelo descrito ou o outro?

Há votos para baseado em opiniões. Sério que não dá para responder objetivamente?

Há até a indicação (não voto) que é *off-topic*. Desde quando perguntas de modelagem e UI são *off-topic*?

Não vou nem entrar no mérito do voto negativo mas como está havendo interpretação errada para o fechamento, certamente está ocorrendo o mesmo se houve ou não esforço de pesquisa ou se a pergunta é útil ou não. Serio que ninguém mais tem essa mesma dúvida?

Mais uma vez o pessoal vota sem entender o que está fazendo. Eu gostaria que não precisasse disto toda vez que é feito uma pergunta conceitual. Mas está aberto o canal para os votantes se manifestarem.

Comment: "_Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de cada um do ponto de vista de modelagem e experiência do usuário?_" . Acho que isso já deixa claro o que o AP quer saber.

Comment: Eu quando preciso fazer uma pergunta desse tipo ponho sempre um bocado de código ou imagem, assim já ninguém se queixa.

Comment: @JorgeB. é, tem que desenhar, né? :P

Comment: @bigown é isso mesmo! As pessoas confundem "não percebo o que ele está perguntando, porque não sei nada sobre isso" com "não é claro o que você está perguntando".

Comment: Existe uma percepção totalmente errada de que qualquer pergunta que não seja "qual é o problema com esse meu código?" deve ser fechada.

Comment: Mais uma: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48665/como-chamar-arquivos-css-utilizando-kohana-php-3-3

Comment: Verdade @bfavaretto.

Comment: Deveriam usar mais o "Pular" nas avaliações.

Comment: Em jeito de declaração de voto: Acho que qualquer reposta será uma questão de opinião ou função de cada caso em particular.

Comment: Impressão minha ou o @bigown arrumou alguns *haters* recentemente?

Comment: @ramaral por isso eu perguntei quais as vantagens e desvantagens de cada um dos dois modelos. Para ter um subsídio para tomar uma decisão no caso particular. As respostas atuais já mostram que há informação que fundamenta isto. Se isto é opinião, qualquer código postado é, porque sempre tem outras formas de fazer no caso específico ou no caso geral. Só porque alguém coloca um código que aparenta funcionar não quer dizer que aquilo está certo, que não dá para contestar. Opinião é algo sem fundamento, sem referência. Mesmo a resposta que não vai no  foco da pergunta tem algum fundamento.

Comment: @rrnan "Recentemente"?!

Comment: @rrnan não sei se é recente mas você matou o problema. Você tem visto negativos sem critério (hoje tive mais negativo de novo, não foi só nessa pergunta), tem quem não vota em positivo em mim, embora muitas vezes o problema de alguns usuário é que eles não gostam de votar positivo em quase ninguém. Já observou quantas pessoas receberam muito mais votos do que deram? E são pessoas bem ativas, não dá para falar que não dá tempo de votar. Eles não votam nem na pergunta que respondem. Tem uns comportamentos muito tribais e egoístas. Acha que agora o pessoal está gostando mais de mim? :P

Comment: Tipo isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48562/101, vai saber o que tem errado. Eu acho que está certo mas se alguém indicar o erro eu conserto ou apago a resposta. Note que este foi um negativo que veio agora que estou em evidência. Fica difícil não achar que é voto de revolta.

Comment: bfavaretto: É que, por mais que tenha conta há quase um ano só passei a frequentar ativamente há alguns meses. Nesse meio tempo, foram nas últimas semanas que vi esses *haters* se manifestando. bigown: Eu só não voto a favor do que não tenho conhecimento (nem por isso voto contra), do contrário acabo votando porque acredito que isso incentiva a participação. Se o *hater* estiver votando em respostas, dá até pra descobrir quem é (porque mostra na reputação), mas se for em pergunta... Seria interessante ter um privilégio que mostrasse quem votou contra :P

Comment: @rrnan eu sou bem observador e conheço bastante a mecânica do *site* quase sempre eu sei quem votou com quase 99% de certeza. Mas tem caso mais complexo que isto. Mas não vou falar nada para não incentivar. Eu nem ligo muito pela reputação negativa. Quase sempre esses negativos injustos geram resultado contrário. Eu não posso reclamar porque estou recebendo votos que provavelmente não receberia se não tivesse ocorrido este fato. O tiro sai pela culatra. Votos devem ser dados por uma razão plausível, com consciência. Eu já recebi negativos justos, não reclamo deles.

Comment: @rrnan Os votos que você dá em série contra ou a favor de alguém são automaticamente revertidos pelo SOpt, que se esforça para que haters e lovers não usem os votos para expressar estes sentimentos. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/930/perda-de-reputa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-repentina-votos-a-favor-em-s%C3%A9rie-revertidos

Comment: Mas algumas pessoas sabem como fazer a reversão não acontecer. Tanto que alguns votos deste tipo que ando recebendo não estão sendo revertidos. Nem estou preocupado com isto, faço limonado do limão que me dão. Mas eles não percebem que deixam rastros para os mais observadores.

Comment: Acredito que o que salva a pergunta de ser listada como ampla demais é a tag modelagem, quando modelamos um sistema temos que analisar diversos pontos de vista e decidir qual melhor caminho a tomar..... a pergunta foi meio que de um analista para outros analistas... em nível de programação ela "até" poderia ser considerada ampla demais.
Enfim, acredito que pelo contexto da pergunta, ela não deva ser fechada

Comment: Em compensação perguntas abertas, sem critérios claros, totalmente baseadas em opinião, que não é possível fundamentar a resposta, que vai produzir respostas acéfalas não gera nenhum interesse em fechar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42383/plugin-de-autocompletar-de-javascript-para-sublime-text-2 Mas eu já cansei de tentar fechar estas estas perguntas, se o resto da comunidade está ok com ela, quem sou eu para questionar. Cansei.

Comment: discordo de fechar essa questão... pois apesar de ser diretamente ligada a modelagem é também na UI e programação.. é um assunto importante pois muitos sistemas criam regras para nomes e sobrenomes que impossibilitam uma pessoa de outro país se cadastrar. Se a modelagem determina um padrão X, esse padrão X será regra na UI. . Essa é a relação..

Answer (score 12):

Eu não acho que a pergunta é off-topic porque ela simplesmente trata de assuntos que são relevantes para esta comunidade, aliás já bem aceitos e fundamentados por muitas outras questões (modelagem, ux e usabilidade, principalmente). Clareza também não parece ser um problema, mas confesso que a minha primeira ideia sobre ela foi que era ampla demais.

Porém, ao tentar respondê-la (principalmente porque eu, em particular, tenho muito interesse no assunto), eu não mais tive a impressão dela ser ampla demais. Talvez ela pudesse ter sido separada em duas perguntas diferentes (vantagens e desvantagens do ponto de vista da modelagem (1) e da experiência de usuário (2)). Porém, depois de dar a minha resposta eu acho que ela faz um certo sentido assim porque não dá pra tomar uma decisão sem a outra (afinal, as escolhas de design que visam elicitar qualquer experiência naturalmente se constroem a partir de decisões de modelagem).

A pergunta é sim subjetiva, mas ela tem cara daquele "subjetivo bom", para o qual é possível sim fornecer respostas objetivas. Aliás, tem muitas outras perguntas similares, que até usam [esse mesmo padrão de perguntar "vantagens e desvantagens"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=vantagens%20e%20desvantagens) e que são também do tipo "subjetivo bom". Essa pergunta, por exemplo, sobre [Vantagens e desvantagens do uso de índices em base de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35088/vantagens-e-desvantagens-do-uso-de-%C3%ADndices-em-base-de-dados) jamais foi questionada e eu nem acho que deva. Ela me parece suficientemente boa para gerar conhecimento útil para a comunidade.

No final, me parece que nesses casos nós gastamos mais tempo julgando as perguntas do que as respostas que lhes são dadas. Será mesmo que essa é a melhor abordagem para que esse conhecimento (que eu pessoalmente julgo importante) não se perca?

Comment: Luiz, a sua resposta lá é bacana mas a conclusão dela **é** a própria pergunta e não difere dos comentários que basicamente dizem que não dá pra responder porque "depende". Pergunta: *"Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de cada um do ponto de vista de modelagem e experiência do usuário?"*. Resposta: *"A escolha depende do domínio da aplicação, principalmente em relação ao uso que será dado para essa informação separada (critério de usabilidade) e à forma como a informação será solicitada e utilizada com o usuário (critério de experiência do usuário)."*.

Comment: Quanto a gastar muito tempo julgando a pegunta, concordo. Ela provavelmente não seria fechada e as respostas seriam dadas sem drama. Por mais que alguém acha que ela seja off-topic, foram poucos. A discussão foi trazida pra cá desnecessariamente.

Comment: De uma certa forma eu fiz a pergunta sabendo que você iria responder, e bem :)

Comment: @Caffé É verdade. Essa é a conclusão. Mas há todo o raciocínio que leva até essa conclusão e que, eu acredito, é o que torna o conteúdo útil não somente ao AP como a outras pessoas da comunidade. É o que eu disse, subjetiva boa. Sobre a discussão ser trazida pra cá desnecessariamente, pode ser que você tenha razão. De todas as formas, é pra isso que serve o meta. É melhor ter essa discussão aqui do que nos comentários lá na pergunta. :)

Comment: @Caffé "Depende" não é sempre uma má resposta, se estiver claro do quê depende não vejo problema nenhum. O que você prefere, uma pergunta de code review que você dá uma resposta absoluta do tipo: "Coloque um ponto-e-vírgula no final da linha 42 que resolve o seu problema", ou uma subjetiva do tópico em questão? Eu prefiro a subjetiva boa, que é útil para muita gente e ainda te põe a pensar, e é aí que as pessoas realmente **aprendem** com o site, enquanto uma pergunta de code review geralmente só é útil para o AP.

Comment: @Math é isto aí. Mas nem sei se é questão depende. Ou talvez tenha um depende implícito na pergunta. Note que eu não perguntei qual devo usar, como é comum nas perguntas. Com as vantagens e desvantagens em mãos, eu vou analisar cada situação que eu tiver, e não será apenas uma, e **dependendo** de cada situação agora com as respostas eu posso aplicar o critério com mais confiança que não está me escapando nada. A pergunta é sobre montagem de requisitos e não como resolve este meu problema aqui. Claro que depende.

Comment: @Math Minhas respostas demonstram que eu gosto de perguntas conceituais. E é claro que tudo depende. Todas as coisas são tão dependíveis que isso até já está implícito em qualquer pergunta e resposta. E perguntas de erro básico de programação como este que você citou são inclusive off-topic segundo regras claras do site, então naturalmente não é o que eu prefiro. De qualquer modo me alegra, no meu último dia de participação no site, esta conversa engajada por um comentário meu que poderia simplesmente ter sido completamente ignorado e a pergunta continuaria lá repleta de votos e respostas. []s

Comment: Na verdade a cominidade não funciona assim. Se eu não fizesse nada, a pergunta poderia ter sido enterrada indevidamente como está sendo demonstrado aqui. Ou você não sabe como a comunidade funciona, ou sabe e fez de propósito para enterrar a pergunta. Eu prefiro acreditar no primeiro. Como ainda tem usuários que ainda não entenderam os critérios normalmente usados obtidos ou por discussões pela comunidade ou influenciadas/impostas pela SE, a discussão sempre caberá. Dar ciência de algo a quem ainda não tem sempre é importante.

Comment: Concordo com o @bigown em que as vezes é realmente importante usar o Meta pra trazer algo à atenção da comunidade. Eu mesmo já [fiz isso isso](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2383/pergunta-suspensa-injustamente) no passado quando julguei que uma pergunta havia sido fechada/suspensa injustamente. Poderia ter feito antes dela ser fechada (quando só havia recebido alguns votos), mas esperei até ela ser fechada. Foi uma escolha minha. Assim como os usuários têm direito de votar pra fechar em seu próprio critério, também têm de abrir uma discussão por aqui. Pra mim é igualmente válido.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, toda essa discussão demonstra que é um caso que levanta dúvidas, por isso acho que alguns votaram pra fechar. Na minha opinião acho que não deveria fechar por nenhum motivo.

**Off-topic**: Acho que não podemos aceitar apenas questões que são 100% programação. Se for 1% já vale.

Exatamente a mesma teoria do futebol. A bola só sai de campo quando passar 100% da linha. Se a bola estiver 0,001% na linha, tá valendo.

Senão acho que teria mais questões fechadas do que abertas no site.

**Não é Claro**: Acho que nem preciso comentar. Pra mim está claríssimo.

**Baseada em Opiniões**: Bem, aí acho que pode haver dúvidas, mas na minha opinião

> Quais as vantagens e desvantagens...

não leva a opiniões, mas o *bonus point* já acho que é realmente questão de opinião.

> Por que isto ocorre por aqui? Seria uma questão cultural histórica?

Comment: Por isto não coloquei como parte fundamental da pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

> Como ser mais claro do que perguntar as vantagens e desvantagens de usar um modelo descrito ou o outro?

Uma maneira de ser mais claro é especificando os parâmetros para avaliação de vantagens e desvantagens. *"Do ponto de vista de modelagem e experiência do usuário"* não são parâmetros válidos porque cada um deles por si só é uma ciência.

> Há até a indicação (não voto) que é off-topic. Desde quando perguntas de modelagem e UI são off-topic?.

**Nem todas são. Esta é**.

Eu escrevi que é off-topic porque esta é a minha avaliação. Naturalmente é a minha avaliação sobre esta pergunta especificamente e não sobre todas as perguntas sobre modelagem e UI (eu provalvelmente devo ter gastado um tempo respondendo outras perguntas de modelagem e UI que considerei válidas e interessantes).

> Sério que ninguém mais tem essa mesma dúvida?

Não sei. Eu não tenho e não conheço ninguém mais que tenha.

> Mais uma vez o pessoal vota sem entender o que está fazendo.

Eu acabei de votar e sabia o que estava fazendo. Embora a sua opinião e a minha possam ser diferentes.

O mecanismo do SOpt está em constante evolução justamente para que a comunidade possa definir o que é melhor para o site dentro da filosofia básica dele. Espera-se que a comunidade atinja este objetivo como um todo e não seguindo uma única linha de raciocínio.

> Eu gostaria que não precisasse disto toda vez que é feito uma pergunta conceitual.

Não creio que precise. Não tem sido preciso em muitas outras perguntas conceituais. Não creio que precisava nem para esta pergunta em específico. Creio que é só deixar o SOpt seguir o seu curso.

## Conclusão:

> Por que esta pergunta deve ser fechada?

Ela só deve ser fechada se a comunidade assim desejar, e neste caso o motivo de fechamento estará informado. Não parece ser o caso de uma discussão sobre o site aceitar ou não perguntas conceituais.

Comment: Por sorte não parece ser o mesmo pesamento da maioria. Eu poderia mostrar os erros na sua avaliação ponto por ponto mas se transformaria em discussão e você não mudaria de ideia. Você apenas colocou sua opinião, não demonstrou que a pergunta realmente tem problemas.

Comment: @bigown O problema da pergunta está explicado logo no primeiro tópico: não é claro o que você está perguntando já que *"do ponto de vista de modelagem e experiência do usuário"* não são parâmetros válidos porque cada um deles por si só é uma ciência.

Comment: Não tem nenhum voto de ampla demais. Depois de horas, é a primeira vez alguém toca nisto. Ainda assim ela é perfeitamente respondível mesmo tratando dos dois pontos de vista. Se talvez até a resposta possa dizer que em ambos é a mesma coisa. Como eu não sei, só alguém respondendo. Mas é claro que você você achou a pergunta interessante. Está perdendo bastante tempo com ela. As perguntas desinteressantes são abandonadas e ninguém fala nada delas.

Comment: @bigown Na verdade o que eu acho interessante é de vez em quando lançar uma voz a favor de respeitar os mecanismos reais do site num esforço de que seu funcionamento não seja dominado pelos top most answers como vem acontecendo com outros sites da rede. Você praticamente criou este site, @bigown; pode deixar agora a cria andar com suas próprias pernas e esperar que ela lhe ensine alguma coisa. Eu particularmente não vou mais te incomodar porque minha participação no site termina amanhã; depois estarei ocupado demais e aparecerei só esporadicamente.Sucesso aí pra você e demais irmãos em código!

Comment: Se não percebeu, nos últimos meses eu tenho deixado o site seguir o seu caminho, eu não tenho tentado mais influenciar como fazia antes, tenho deixado d fazer muita coisa q fazia antes, tenho deixado o fluxo seguir e estou aceitando o q ñ gostaria d ver no site. Não me preocupo mais. Justamente qdo houve esta mudança de postura e comecei me preocupar só com o uso do site começou uma onde de menos de meia dúzia achando que eu estou fazendo algo indesejável. Mas tudo de acordo com o que foi definido pela comunidade. Não sou o ponto fora da curva neste caso.