# Por que um moderador responde a uma pergunta, e outro a fecha?

Tags: debate, razões-fechamento, moderação

Ontem, 15/02/2020, um [usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/109835/eduardo-candido) postou a seguinte pergunta:

- [Pegar o menor valor de um array de objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/435941/8063)

Um **moderador** postou uma resposta e depois um outro **moderador** a fechou pelo motivo "[fora de escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)".

Fiquei confuso no sentido de que: se um **moderador**, que tem o mesmo poder de fechar a pergunta, **a respondeu** (inclusive sua resposta foi marcada com ✔️) e outro **moderador** a fechou pelo motivo "[fora de escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)", porquê o **moderador** que respondeu, em vez de ter fechado a pergunta, não a fechou, mas foi outro **moderador** que a fechou?

Ou seja, um moderador responde e outro fecha?

Gostaria de entender qual o critério disso, pois me pareceu meio que um contrassenso.

---

<sup>**Obs.:** Faço esta pergunta isento de qualquer tipo de sentimento. É apenas para entender mesmo.</sup>

Comment: Vou mais longe, tem algumas que eu respondi e acabei fechando depois. Se nisso não vejo contrasenso, também não veria em fechar de outro moderador. Inclusive, se fosse para ter decisão unânime, nem precisariamos ter mais de um né? Para sermos práticos, se acha que o fechamento foi correto, nenhum problema a ser resolvido. Se acha que o fechamento foi errado, basta votar para reabrir - a idéia é que a comunidade seja auto-regulável. Em geral, o moderador age em cima da inércia desta.

Comment: Não existe critério na utilização do Off-topic ao meu ver. Inclusive eu não vejo motivo na utilização nessa pergunta.

Comment: @Bacco Na verdade nem achei que o fechamento foi incorreto ou correto. Fiquei curioso em entender esses critérios porque achei meio estranho. Mas a resposta abaixo já clarificou tudo. A gente aprende às vezes perguntando né? =]

Comment: @Diogo da minha parte existe critério,**só não é um que você goste**. Ele foi adotado depois de discussões, está na resposta aqui e em outros lugares mostrados para você. Pode dar sua opinião, mas não espalhe informações falsas, porque inclusive vai parecer que você não tem critério para fazer criticas. Pode ver na resposta que tem pessoas com critérios inconsistentes, e tem muitas.Na resposta mostra que tem pessoas que tem critério diferente do meu e que mesmo assim tem critério.O fato de vc ñ ver motivo só mostra q você não sabe ou não entende o critério do q foi estabelecido pela comunidade

Comment: @Sam para reflexão => https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2412/porque-esta-pergunta-deve-ser-fechada Pergunta muito boa inclusive.

Comment: Viu lá como se produz um debate saudável, sem acusações, e pessoas ponderadas falam o que pensam sem ataques e aí chega-se em algo que pode ser útil para a comunidade? Pena que tudo lá ficou datado, e fazia sentido na época que o site tinha mais qualidade.

Comment: @Maniero peguei uma pergunta sua justamente para mostrar que acho o seu trabalho bom, não tenho nada contra você. Sua pergunta é ótima e muito pertinente neste momento.

Comment: @Diogo Aproveitando a questão, tem coisa pior quando usuário dá negativo esdrúxulo. Tem duas respostas iguais, uma ele negativa, a outra não. Aí você vai ver a pessoa tem birra com você, vive fazendo coisa errada, não positiva quem sempre recebe positivo e negativa tão concentrado que está prestes a se tornar a maior negativadora em cima desse usuário que é alvo dele com o voto dado nessa madrugada. Essa pessoa negativa poucas pessoas, tem 3 que ele já demonstrou publicamente ter birra que tem vários negativos, o resto ele não negativa. Acha que é só falta de critério ou é perseguição mesmo?

Comment: @Maniero bom, acho que isso é uma questão pessoal, eu não dou negativo para ninguém. Pontuação é coisa secundária.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O principal motivo é que cada pessoa tem seu critério específico. Não existe essa coisa de uma única moderação absolutamente consistente, isso está na base da eleição, e já foi discutido em algum lugar que o ideal é que moderadores sejam diferentes, ainda que eu acho que deve haver alguma linha base, não dá para moderadores ficarem se digladiando publicamente o tempo todo, até porque algumas pessoas entendem isso como algo negativo (alguns ficarão fazendo até torcida, vibrarão com a maturidade de 15 anos quando um moderador reverteu algo de outro que ela não gosta, sabe? tipo quando professor erra e vira uma alegria dos alunos?).

E se não quiser entender melhor, isso já responde a pergunta e pode pular todo o resto.

Eu só não posso responder porque o moderador que respondeu não fechou, posso especular. E a resposta pode ser só "esse casos específico eu achei que era ok responder".

No passado eu provavelmente deixaria aberta, até que houve uma mudança debatida. Talvez negativaria pela falta de esforço, mas tenho evitado porque tem muitas perguntas muito piores que merecem mais, tenho guardado para elas. E essa era salvável, pra mim negativo funciona melhor para aqueles que você sabe que não salva, ou só salva mudando completamente, até que seja outra pergunta.

## Moderação coletiva

Uma coisa que muitos não sabem é que alguns moderadores me questionam sobre algo e minha resposta em quase todos os casos, quando eu mesmo não vejo como um erro, é que se ela pensa diferente, ela pode reverter o que eu fiz. Tem alguns casos que a certeza é muito grande e acho que uma reversão causaria mais dano, mas nunca falo isso porque não quero ver minha decisão revertida.

Nem todos moderadores fazem isso.

## Problema da pergunta

A pergunta é um enunciado. Claramente é isso, ela disse o que queria e esperava que alguém adivinhasse todo o contexto em volta e respondesse. Eu entendo que um novato não perceba que isso é ruim, mas usuários experientes no site já deveriam ter aprendido que não costuma ser boas perguntas, o AP vai adorar a resposta, mesmo que caia no que eu sempre falo:

[image: Fiat 1476 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Eu estou dizendo que as respostas estão erradas? Não, se fosse o caso, eu teria negativado. Pra falar a verdade eu nem li as respostas. Com a carga intensa de moderação eu tento otimizar o tempo.

Ali não tem um problema específico, tem um problema genérico anunciado. Não é uma questão conceitual. Mas se quiser pode-se dizer que não tem toda informação para dar uma resposta específica.

Dá pra discutir a questão? Dá, mas quanto mais fazemos isso mais criamos zonas cinzentas.

Vou dar um exemplo do que não foi considerado. A pergunta tem a *tag* AngularJS. Porque as respostas não consideraram isso? Provavelmente a pessoa nem use AngularJS, mas uma versão mais recente? Sim. Ela deve ter colocado de alegre? Sim. Talvez não faça diferença estar usando Angular? Talvez. Não temos como saber, ninguém pensou nisso antes de responder, pode ter algo escondido na pergunta, ela é só um enunciado muito mal escrito, fica claro que a pessoa não tem noção do que ela está perguntando. E lendo agora eu daria resposta diferente das que foram dadas.

## Padrão estabelecido

Já houve época que até aceitamos algo assim, mas era pouco, e não víamos que costumava descarrilhar rápido. Mesmo queno não parece ir mal ninguém sabe se é uma boa resposta porque a pergunta nunca está clara, sempre tem algum requisito que falta. Sempre tem um detalhe que faz a resposta não ser adequada, e sempre a pessoa aceita porque ela é ingênua e não sabe avaliar o que é bom. Ela quer uma ajuda qualquer, e isso é o maior motivo para fechar esse tipo de pergunta, ela não quer uma resposta que mate a questão de forma inequívoca. Ela acha que o SOpt é um *help desk* individual.

Eu fiz isso: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101). Teve ampla aceitação. Nem todos leram. Alguns talvez discordem. Ali é um resumo de como são as regras e práticas do site. Ali claramente mostra que esse tipo de pergunta é ruim e não deveria ser feita, muito menos respondida. É o tipo de pergunta mais tem causado problema, alguns visíveis, outros nem tanto, mas os que não seguem a linha "bumba meu boi" de que o importante é funcionar, sabe que uma resposta pode até ser boa, mas também pode ser prejudicial, pode estar criando uma receita de bolo indevida.

Inúmeras discussões sobre isso foram feitas, e foi amplamente aceito que isso é problema, inclusive alguns casos pode-se dizer unanimemente, até onde dá para dizer quando as pessoas participam opcionalmente. Não deveria ser algo duvidoso para ninguém.

## Aceitação

Aceitação, como muitos sabem, não quer dizer nada além de que o AP gostou da resposta, e olhe lá, alguns aceitam e dizem que a resposta não respondeu o que ele queria. Muitas vezes aquilo só deu um norte pra ela. Ela aceitou e depois viu que não servia bem para o que ela queria, ou muito mais pra frente, descobre que as respostas até lhe prejudicaram, mas no momento inicial ela não conseguia dizer isso. É duro ter que ficar repetindo isso.

Votos também não indica qualidade da resposta. Todos sabem que a maioria dá *like* e não "corrige" a questão como se fosse uma prova, ou mesmo quando faz, muitas vezes a pessoa não é qualificada para qualificar aquilo.

E claro que dá uma indicação que as pessoas gostaram do conteúdo, mas aceitação, nem isso pode ser garantido, ela só está agradecida, por isso a SE está pra tirar de vez a pinagem, se não desistirem. A aceitação pode ser correta, mas não uma prova definitiva que a resposta é boa. Em perguntas mal formuladas a chance de ser correta diminui, e pode até ser, mas por coincidência. Mais um indicativo do problema da pergunta.

## Participação da comunidade e moderação

Nem todos no site participam ativamente do site. Você vê todos moderadores participando do meta?

Quando as pessoas vão participando menos elas começam ficar defasadas das decisões tomadas no site. Elas aceitam o que foi decidido, como é na vida real quando a pessoa não vota ou anula o voto, quando não protesta por contra ou a favor de algo. Mas todos devem seguir o que foi estabelecido. Pode-se sempre discutir de novo e obter apoio para mudar, mas não pode mudar no grito.

Eu acho que a comunidade deve participar mais, quem sabe salvar a pergunta antes. Mas dá mais trabalho salvar uma pergunta, melhor responder logo, né?. Questionamentos, pedidos e edições ali poderiam ter feito a pergunta ficar melhor e se tornar uma pergunta canônica que ajudasse todos.

Eu só lamento que nem todos estejam em sintonia com oque é discutido. Eu lamento que algumas pessoas querem transformar o site em Yahoo! Respostas. Mas lamento que façam isso mais na base do "eu vou fazer como eu acho melhor" do que discutindo o assunto e conseguindo apoio.

Eu ando refletindo sobre o assunto, e tem hora que penso se não deveria abrir a porteira e responder qualquer coisa. Há algumas pressões para acontecer. Mas aí lembro que se fizer isso não temos mais razão para existir. Já tem muito lugar que faz isso, pra que ser mais um? O SO nasceu para ser diferente. Alguns querem algo oposto, mas não foi isso que fez as pessoas adorarem a plataforma. Não foi o que essas pessoas se comprometerem. Quem quer algo frouxo que não busque o máximo da qualidade encontra em outros sites algo mais adequado para elas.

Agora, o que faz o SO ter o sucesso que tem é a qualidade. Pelo menos a tentativa de obtê-la. E hoje já tem uma fama ruim, já passou do ponto que poderíamos dizer que o site é o máximo em qualidade. Mas ainda tem alguma, não podemos perder isso, é o que nos diferencia. Respostas para perguntas que não tem detalhes, que qualquer coisa pode funcionar, mas nenhuma estar certa, ou estar só por coincidência não queria conteúdo de qualidade. Mesmo que certo, a coincidência tira o selo de qualidade.

O dia que aceitar qualquer coisa a deterioração vai aumentando e logo as pessoas dirão que já não acha nada bom so SOen ou SOpt (o que já começou acontecer).

Quando você tem um caso ou outro é só ruído, quando começa ter muito vai atraindo mais casos assim e passa ser total poluição, começa se destacar e ofusca o bom conteúdo. Quem participa ativamente do site e se preocupa com a questão vê isso acontecendo.

Eu acho que a comunidade pode mudar algo, pro bem ou pro mal. Se tomarem pro mal, eu respeito, pelo menos no sentido de aceitar o fato, embora eu perca o respeito pelo site e aí eu terei certeza que não é o site que eu quero participar. Eu acho que as pessoas devem usar o site que elas se sintam confortáveis. Eu tenho tentando fazer com que o SOpt seja pra mim e tenho conseguido apoio. Nem sempre, pro bem ou mal do site. Eu cedo em uma quantidade incrível de coisas que eu acho que ele deveria ser diferente do que é, mas nada que o torne inviável pra mim. O site nunca será perfeito pra qualquer pessoa.

Para citar [um exemplo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7855/101) que a comunidade pode fazer a diferença em propor o padrão, eu propus algo que muitos pediram antes, sempre teve perguntas sobre o assunto e que cai no critério de poder dar boas respostas e que ajude muitas pessoas. Ou seja, por coerência as pessoas deveriam apoiar em massa. Eu acho que teve um bom apoio ali. Mas 16 votos na pergunta pode ser só que o assunto deve ser discutido. Teve 4 votos em resposta que disse que não deveria fazer isso. Eu poderia considerar que teve apoio, mas preferi ir pelo caminho mais seguro e não adotar. As pessoas não foram claras em que discordar das 5 pessoas que consideraram que aquilo não deveria ser adotado. Note que eu bolei algo para não causar problemas, algo que seria curado.

## Conclusão da pergunta

Está implicitamente propondo algo? Seria uma proposta de que se um moderador responder algo não deve ser fechado? Deve haver dois pesos e duas medidas quando um moderador está envolvido? Devemos desconsiderar o que foi estabelecido para privilegiar um moderador?

Ou está dizendo que se um moderador fez algo ele não pode ser contestado por ninguém, nem mesmo por outro moderador?

Eu sei, é só uma dúvida. Mas dúvidas suscitam possíveis entendimentos, certos ou errados, precisamos entender se é o caso para ver se algo precisa ser feito, afinal é um debate.

Eu poderia dizer que é um contrassenso achar que um moderador não pode fechar algo que outro respondeu.

Eu poderia deixar tudo isso pra lá e me pouparia todo esse trabalho. Mas ainda meu comprometimento com o site é maior.

## Por que não teve a mesma dúvida quando ocorreu em vários outros casos?

Por exemplo esta: [Qual a forma correta de inserir um dado necessário em um construtor no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/434947/101). 5 pessoas votaram para fechar, inclusive um moderador. Eu acho que os 5 estão errados.

Eu não gosto muito desse motivo porque ele não é específico e dá margem para interpretação, mas vou considerar que todos perceberam que ele pode ser reproduzido (o código não funcionar é diferente não poder reproduzir, em geral reprodução é de erro mesmo), então é um erro de digitação. Mas a pessoa aprender em um curso algo errado, certamente não é erro de digitação. O conhecimento ali é útil para muitas pessoas, ensina algo em cima de uma pergunta clara para o que é relevante, e razoavelmente bem feita (não nota 10).

Não entender uma sintaxe e dar erro é diferente de ser um erro de digitação. Ali tem um problema caro e específico de algo que a pessoa tentou.

E a fila foi puxada por uma pessoa que não costuma fechar quase nada, muita coisa ruim deixa passar, e parecia interessado em responder, mas depois que eu respondi a pergunta passou ser ruim, como mostra os comentários confusos. E lembremos que é uma pessoa que tem um histórico de fazer coisas contra mim. Boa parte dos fechamentos que participa é em perguntas que eu respondi.

É verdade que essa pessoa talvez tenha sido a mais coerente porque votou como não clara, embora parece que a falta de clareza seja a falta do *link* para o curso, o que é irrelevante para a dúvida. Ajudaria a gente ver com os próprios olhos e começar não recomendar o curso, mas não faria a dúvida ficar mais clara. Está bem claro ali o que a pessoa quer saber, e ela inclusive tentou e não funcionou. A dúvida independe do curso, ou se ele se confundiu com algo, ele aprendeu algo errado e que existe em outro contexto.

Por mim reabriria, mas vão dizer que eu fiz porque era do meu interesse, então eu deixei. Esse tipo de fechamento é o que dá fama do SOpt não gostar de perguntas de novatos, que é falso, no geral, mas esse é um caso que o defeito dela é ser básica, é ter sido feita porque a pessoa confiou em um curso ruim. Pra mim o SOpt é justamente para resolver esse tipo de coisa. Mas eu respeito a opinião de outros, ao contrário de algumas pessoas que me comparam com um genocida. Claro que tem casos e casos.

Eu podia ter trazido para o meta. Mas eu cansei de fazer isso, é muito trabalho para pouca coisa, melhor deixar lá, não muda a vida de ninguém ficar aberta oi fechada. O conhecimento está dado e algumas pessoas expressaram que acham que não é uma boa pergunta para o site.

Eu acho que posso dar algumas possibilidades de não ter reclamado. Uma delas é que não viu. Outra é que não gosta de quem respondeu e achou que era melhor ficar assim mesmo. Note que não estou dizendo que essas coisas aconteceram, são apenas possibilidades. Pode ser que ache que foi bem fechada e não tinha porque reclamar, o que eu acho menos provável porque raramente participa de fechamentos e em geral não fecharia essa também, não fechou várias outras piores que essa, e estou falando de grande volume e não um caso ou outro, que poderia ter caído no primeiro motivo que eu dei. Pode ser que achou que o fato de ter outras pessoas fechando legitimaria mais. Pode ser outro motivo que eu nem consegui pensar agora, ou preferi não falar, alguns bons, outros ruins. Não seria produtivo ficar tentando achar.

As pessoas podem ter motivações diversas.

A pergunta tem votos para reabrir, uma delas que já deu demonstrações que pega no meu pé, mas pra ela o mais importante ali é fazer o certo, dentro da motivação dela. EU não vou perguntar para cada um dos 5 porque fecharam ou dos que votaram para reabrir, pode chegar a 6 porque reabriram. Eu já o fiz no começo do site, porque estávamos aprendendo como é o comportamento da comunidade. Eu entendo uma pessoa novata perguntando, ainda que pode pesquisar no meta discussões anteriores.

Eu poderia pegar outro exemplo que o moderador ali fechou sozinho ou até que o Sergio ou outro moderador fechou uma pergunta que eu respondi, tem bastante caso mas não tenho paciência para usar o SEDE para achar algo. Tem pergunta que moderador removeu o que eu respondi. Poucas pessoas veem tudo o que acontece, inclusive porque uma parte nem é público.

Eu já fechei várias [perguntas que eu respondi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/430811/101). Em geral eu achei que a pergunta era boa, aí a pessoa começa comentar e mostra que era outra coisa. No fim era tão ruim, nem dava para perceber a ruindade toda. Esses casos **eu errei em ter respondido**. E vou aprendendo que muitas vezes é melhor fechar. Aí que em casos assim pode não ser tão grave porque gera uma discussão e as pessoas ficam sabendo que tem problemas ali. Pior é quando parece que tudo está ótimo e não estar.

## Por que votou para fechar uma que pede basicamente a mesma coisa?

[Como descobrir todos os possíveis caminhos para visitar todos os vértices de um grafo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/426570/101). É um enunciado pedindo uma solução, igual a que não entendeu o fechamento e que achou que não deve fechar. Inconsistência entre duas pessoas diferentes é normal, mas o que explica inconsistência da mesma pessoa com uma diferença tão pequena de dias (, o voto foi dado há poucos dias, se fosse em outro ano bem anterior poderia ser que mudou de opinião, geral)?

[Como programar em java e python junto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/430218/101). Considerou que devia deixar fechada.

Tem vários casos que deu voto para fecha, mas não foi fechada porque não houve conformação por outras pessoas. Exemplo: [Somar colunas de uma matriz por linha e colocar o total em uma nova coluna](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/430061/101) (eu fechei agora, algumas a gente não vê). Um enunciado que só diz o que quer, idêntica ao que está questionando. Então por que uma que respondeu não devia ser fechada seguindo o mesmo critério?

[function javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/423561/101). Votou para manter fechada, essa tem até mais detalhes que a que está questionando, ainda que está bem desleixa, editaram mas não melhoraram onde podia ter salvo a pergunta.

[Como consultar vários select em somente uma linha sql para obter 7 resultado diários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/430200/101). Se essa que a pessoa tentou e encontrou problemas é para fechar, imagina uma que a pessoa nem tentou.

Eu poderia fazer uma análise de várias outras olhando os *logs* disponíveis no site. Em alguns casos a pessoa erra, outros a pessoa tem um critério específico, tem casos que o contexto é outro, tem caso que há discordância, e há mudança de opinião ao longo do tempo, mas também existe o voto dado sem critério ou o voto deixado de dar sem critério também, que eu acho que causa muito mais estrago. Eu não vou julgar o que aconteceu em cada caso porque não estou na cabeça das pessoas, mas quando a pessoa faz muito algo começa dar pistas sobre o que acontece.

## Conclusão

Você tem poder de pelo menos iniciar o fechamento a pergunta, por que não o fez e respondeu? Discorda do caso específico? Discorda que perguntas que são apenas enunciado devem ser fechadas? Mudou de opinião essa semana? Participou das discussões sobre isso? Conseguiu dar bons argumentos? Acha que depois de tomada a decisão, deve fazer o oposto do que foi decidido? Ou apenas não sabia de nada disso? E daí veio a dúvida.

Eu discordo da ação do Sergio, mas não considero que ele tenha sido incoerente, e ele fez o que sempre faz. Ele deve discordar da minha ação, mas é o que eu faço há bastante tempo, e faria menos se a comunidade ajudasse mais fazer o conteúdo ser melhor, que salvasse mais as perguntas que não estão boas mas tem um tema que merece alguma atenção, e resposta depois de melhorada.

<sub>É possível observar ações inconscientes das pessoas que contradizem o que elas dizem, mesmo em textos. Dizer que não há sentimento envolvido e negritar tantas vezes a palavra moderador parece mostrar haver sentimento, claro não há garantias dessa análise, mas é sempre algo possível, e o fato de dizer que não há sentimento tende indicar que é o que a pessoa está pensando, mesmo que ninguém mais tenha pensado nisso, mas acho menos provável, parece ser mais cuidado por causa de experiências anteriores</sub>

Comment: PS: Quando votei para fechar a pergunta [Qual a forma correta de inserir um dado necessário em um construtor no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/434947/qual-a-forma-correta-de-inserir-um-dado-necess%c3%a1rio-em-um-construtor-no-php) eu fui atrás do material que AP daquela pergunta citou para confrontar e a fonte é essa https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-metodo-construtor-testes-21041 que em momento algum aparece a recomendação que o AP daquela questão afirmou ter sido passada adiante.

Comment: @AugustoVasques isso é uma explicação, e mostra, se foi isso mesmo, que a pessoa se embananou toda, mas ainda não é um erro de digitação. Essa informação, se comentada lá ajudaria entender o voto e daria alguma margem de interpretação e ajudaria validar a decisão, e até seria instrutivo para todos. Eu fico um pouco mais em cima do muro sabendo disso, mas ainda não tenho certeza que essa pergunta  é um erro de digitação, ninguém erra algo nesse nível só por digitação. Tem uma falta de conhecimento envolvido. Não reabri porque nunca considerei um erro crasso, só diferença de interpretação.

Comment: Li mais ou menos a resposta por falta de tempo agora devido ela ser muito longa (depois a lerei mais calma). Eu achava que os moderadores tinham uma linha de pensamento única em comum. Mas diante do esclarecido é aceitável que isso não seja verdade.

Comment: @AugustoVasques no caso dessa aí, no meu entender, o cara inventou sintaxe, provavelmente pra mim coisa desse tipo vai sempre ser erro de digitação. Justamente cai naquilo de cada um ter uma visão da coisa. Se ele tivesse apontado ao menos algo parecido no manual e tivesse confundido, ainda daria pra pensar, mas nem na documentação citada e nem na oficial tem nada que sequer parece com a tentativa.